# multiple info window on MAP

Tags: android, api, google-maps, infowindow

I am working on an android application which majorly uses Google MAP API.
Currently, google MAP api allows only single info window over the markers. I need to put text OR image on all the markers over the map, and display all info windows at the same time.

Does anybody have any idea how can we do that ?

Comment: do you get the answer yet? i need the same feature as you do i still find no solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have got your answer. As my answer will be helpful for others.

You will need to create a your own [InfoWindowAdapter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) to show multiple info in the infoWindow.

```
setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame 
        @Override 
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null; 
        } 

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow 
        @Override 
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout 
            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
            v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet());
            ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            markerIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.back_vision_fade); 
            return v;

        }
    });
```